# How many types of reshut exist?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, eruv-chatzerot

I know that there is a public domain (*reshut ha-rabbim*) and a private domain (*reshut ha-yahid*), but are there other types of *reshuyoth* mentioned in the *halakhah* of carrying on *Shabbat*?

Answer (score 5):

[Halachipedia](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Hotzah) says:

> **Definition of the 4 domains**
>
> There are 4 categories of domains on Shabbat: the Reshut HaRabim
>   (public domain), Reshut HaYachid (private domain), intermediate area
>   (Karmelit), and exempt area (Makom Patur).
>
> A Reshut HaYachid is defined as an area of at least 4 Tefachim by 4
>   Tefachim surrounded by walls of at least 10 Tefachim. This includes a
>   pit which is 4x4 Tefachim with walls of 10 Tefachim.
>
> A Reshut HaRabim is defined as a street which is 16 amot wide. Some
>   say that if there's not 600,000 people passing through it daily it's
>   not a Reshut HaRabim.
>
> A Karmelit is defined as an area of 4 Techaim by 4 Tefachim with walls
>   which are less than 10 Tefachim in height. It also includes areas
>   where the public doesn't walk and doesn't have proper fencing such as
>   fields, or rivers which are 10 Tefachim deep.
>
> A Makom Patur is a place which is less than 4 Tefachim by 4 Tefachim
>   but is of at least 3 Tefachim in height. They are only a Makom Patur
>   when placed in a Reshut HaRabim, but in a Karmelit they are considered
>   like a Karmelit.

Comment: I think you could add a few points to make this more complete:

1- In the Torah, there is no concept of karmelis. It's the rabbis who separated off those private domains that might be confused with a reshus harabbim, and made a separate category out of it.

2- The source for the 4 reshuyos of Shabbos is Shabbos 6a:


3- The OP didn't limit itself to Shabbos. There are public and private domains in fiscal discussions (damages when someone else is on my property, damages due to my negligence in the public domain, ...) and in tum'ah and taharah, neither of which fall along exactly the same lines.

Comment: @MichaBerger Thank you for points 1 and 2. Re point 3, it depends if you take the title of the question or the elaboration of it in the text "but are there other types of reshuyoth **mentioned in the halakhah of carrying on Shabbat?**"